# cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element for RootElement

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I've following schema using which i have generated the jaxb object. I'm populating the jaxb object with data and then marshaling it.I want to do schema validation while marshaling the jaxb object.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream formXml = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

new JAXBElement<Form100DIV_V100>(new QName("http://example.org/types/2003/04", "Form100DIV_V100"), Form100DIVV100.class, (Form100DIVV100) form100);

 if (isSchemaValidationNeeded) {
            SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

            InputStream xsdStream = XmlUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("schema/form.xsd");
            StreamSource xsdSource = new StreamSource(xsdStream);
            Schema schema = sf.newSchema(xsdSource);

            //m.setEventHandler(new SchemaValidationEventHandler());
            //m.setSchema(schema);

            Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
            try {
              validator.validate(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(formXml.toByteArray())));
              System.out.println("File is valid");
            } catch (SAXException e) {
              System.out.println("File is NOT valid");
              System.out.println("Reason: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://example.org/types/2003/04" targetNamespace="http://example.org/types/2003/04" 
elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

 <xs:complexType name="Form100DIV_V100">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="AbstractForm100">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="AMOUNT" type="AmountType" minOccurs="0"/>
               ---
           </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
----
-----
</xs:schema>
```

Here is the xml which i'm getting after marshaling

```
<Form100DIV_V100 xmlns="http://example.org/types/2003/04">
  <AMOUNT>100.00</AMOUNT>
  -------
  ---------
</Tax1099Div_V100>
```

I'm getting below error though namespaces are correct in xml and xsd.
    Reason: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'Form100DIV_V100'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Form100DIV_V100` is not defined in your schema as a top level element, only as a type. You can simply just wrap the `xs:complexType` in a `xs:element`

   ```
   <xs:element name="Form100DIV_V100">
     <xs:complexType>
       <xs:complexContent>
         <xs:extension base="AbstractForm100">
           <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element name="AMOUNT" type="AmountType" minOccurs="0" />
           </xs:sequence>
         </xs:extension>
       </xs:complexContent>
     </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
   ```
2. In your xml instance, `<Form100DIV_V100>` is not terminated correctly. You are terminating it with `</Tax1099Div_V100>`.

   ```
   <Form100DIV_V100 xmlns="http://example.org/types/2003/04">
     <AMOUNT>100.00</AMOUNT>
   </Form100DIV_V100>
   ```

Given you have `AbstractForm100` and `AmountType` types correctly defined and the rest of your `-----`s are correct, the above fixes should validate.

Also, compiling with xjc should give you a `Form100DIVV100` defined with a necessary `@XmlRootElement` annotation for your class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Form100DIV_V100")
public class Form100DIVV100 extends AbstractForm100 {
```

Though it doesn't look like